# When I clicked UITextField which is UITableViewCell's subview to edit, it will run cross textFieldShouldBeginEditing then Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, ios11

Xcode : XCode 9.4.1, Macbook : High Sierra v.10.13.5

I used tag to decide which action every textField will take in method textFieldShouldBeginEditing.

Recently, I found it will crash when return YES in iPhone SE.

(iPhone 8 and iPhone X will be fine)

(Every textField which uses return NO and does activity will also be fine.)

Does anyone know what happened it is ?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSInteger tag = textField.tag;

    if (tag == dateTag) {
       [self showDatePicker];
       return NO;
    }

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rebecca, welcome to StackOverflow. What error are you seeing when your app crashes?

Comment: Do you have an error shown in console when it crashes?